# How do I resolve this error? AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to implement neural style transfer by using the code in [this](https://medium.com/artists-and-machine-intelligence/neural-artistic-style-transfer-a-comprehensive-look-f54d8649c199) article. When I run main.py I get the error in the title of my question referring to line 12. I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with `torch.randn(input.data.size())` but I don't know what to do about it. I'm still a beginner with machine learning and I'm still learning things about Python as well. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from StyleCNN import *
from utils import *

# CUDA Configurations
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.FloatTensor

# Content and style
style = image_loader("style.jpg").type(dtype)
content = image_loader("content.jpg").type(dtype)

pastiche = image_loader("content.jpg").type(dtype)
pastiche.data = torch.randn(input.data.size()).type(dtype)

num_epochs = 31


def main():
    style_cnn = StyleCNN(style, content, pastiche)

    for i in range(num_epochs):
        pastiche = style_cnn.train()

        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Iteration: %d" % (i))

            path = "outputs/%d.png" % (i)
            pastiche.data.clamp_(0, 1)
            save_image(pastiche, path)


main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
You have multiple references to ".data"; you should test and print the data type of each object?

Comment: what is "input" ? is it a variable? I m asking this question because in python "input" is a built-in function which doesn't have an attribute of name "data"  (look 'input.data')

Comment: After taking a closer look at the code in the article, I think the author meant to write pastiche.data.size().